# How to create and consume a WCF in angularjs in mvc .net?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, wcf, angularjs-scope, wcf-binding

In Wcf:

file(EmployeeServices.svc.cs):

```
public class EmployeeServices : IEmployeeServices
{

[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       UriTemplate = "Employee")]
    public List<Employee> EmployeeDetail()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblEmployees", con))
            {

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Employee emp = new Employee();
                    emp.Id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                    emp.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                    emp.Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString();

                    emp.Salary = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Salary"]);
                    employeeList.Add(emp);
                }

            }
        }
        return employeeList;

    }
}
```

And file(IEmployeeServices.cs):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEmployeeServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Employee> EmployeeDetail();
}
```

And file(Employee.cs):

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

In Angularjs application:

```
     var app = angular
    .module("myModule", [])
    .controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {

        $http.get("EmployeeService.asmx/EmployeeDetail")
             .then(function (response) {
                 $scope.employees = response.data;
             });
    });
```

I am not able to execute the wcf service and how can I check it? Then I need to consume on Angularjs application.

Comment: If you are new to this, is there any particular reason why you decided to use WCF instead of [WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api), for which there are tons of examples for?

Comment: Actually i m following some videos so in tht they have used web service i tried with tht also  but it didnt work so i move to wcf but still not working out for me @NightOwl888

Comment: I am just saying, there is a running joke at Microsoft that WCF actually stands for "Windows Complication Foundation". WebApi is the much newer and much easier to configure option, and I would recommend it over WCF if you are just starting out.